# What is the codec that increases resolution of image upon adding further data?

Tags: image-processing, image-formats

On some websites I've seen images that 1st appear bit blurred and then they gradually get better in steps. What is the image codec? Is it PNG? In "The Social Network" The movie title is displayed in similar fashion. It gets more detailed gradually and finally the title appears in its full resolution. I think they've splendidly showcased a real codec that does that. What are the codecs of that sort? They are very helpful in HTTP protocol. And also in my undergrad I remember my lecturer explaining similar digital image processing mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

It's called progressive loading. For .JPG, save file as "Progressive JPEG" and that's it. Progressive .jpegs when downloading, show at full size but blurry until fully downloaded.

Comment: what abt pngs? they got adam7 interlacing algorithm. Is it similar to that of jpegs? and does every jpeg is of the sort?

Comment: @jmiserez for http://superuser.com/questions/776511/can-we-change-jpeg-image-size-with-out-decoding-and-re-encoding#comment-1009886 says progressive JPEG just sends a low resolution pic in the beginning.